# adjust x axis dates to match start of the ("fiscal") year

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to shift the dates of a seasonal graph so that they match an arbitrary fiscal year (for example MARCH/FEB instead of DEC/JAN)?

I have this of far:

```
startMonth = 3 # march
startDate = as.Date(paste0(year(today()), '-', startMonth, '-1'))


dts = seq.Date(from = today() - 500, to = today(), by = 'day')
dat = data.frame(date = dts, value = runif(n = length(dts), min = 1, max = 10))

dat$month = month(dat$date)
dat$year = year(dat$date)
dat$yearPlot = ifelse(test = dat$month < startMonth, yes = (dat$year - 1), no = dat$year)
dat$year = as.character(dat$year)

dat$ydaydiff = yday(dat$date) - yday(startDate)
dat$datePlot1 = ifelse(dat$ydaydiff < 0, dat$ydaydiff + 365, dat$ydaydiff)
dat$datePlot1 = as.Date('0001-01-01') + days(dat$datePlot1)

dat$yearPlot = as.character(dat$yearPlot)
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_path(aes(x = datePlot1, y = value, color = yearPlot)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%b', )
```

Which makes this plot: 
[image]

However I'd like the x-axis to start at March instead of Jan. Is there any way to adjust this? I thought of using the `month` column in `dat` but not sure how to implement.

Comment: Do you also want `dat$year` to reflect the FY, instead of calendar year?

Comment: I stored FY in yearPlot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not-too-pretty solution. The logic somewhat follows your own: find the starting date/time for each fiscal year (March 1 = time 1) and the last date/time (Feb 28 = time 365). Use this separate 'time' variable as your x-axis, then re-label the tick marks. You can change the `scale_x_continuous()` breaks and labels to get your desired dates along the x-axis.

```r
t <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(as.Date('2018-03-01'),as.Date('2020-02-28'),by='days'),
                fy=1)
t$fy[t$date>='2019-03-01'] <- 2
t <- t %>% group_by(fy) %>% mutate(time=seq(1:n()))

dat <- left_join(dat,t) 
dat %>% ggplot(.) +
  geom_path(aes(x = time, y = value, color = factor(fy),group=fy)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,100,200,300),labels=c('March 1','June 8','Sept 16','Dec 25'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `breaks_width` argument to `scale_x_date()` allows you to offset the breaks by a few months in a year.

The `labels` argument accepts a function to format the labels as a fiscal year, e.g. to convert a date `2019-03-01` to `"19/20"`.

```
# Function to create fiscal year labels like "14/15" for the 2014/15 fiscal year
fiscal_year <- function(x) {
  year_number <- lubridate::year(x)
  paste(substr(year_number, 3, 4),
        substr(year_number + 1, 3, 4),
        sep = "/")
}

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_path(aes(x = date, y = value, color = yearPlot)) +
  scale_x_date(labels = fiscal_year, # Use the function to create the labels
               breaks = scales::breaks_width("1 year", offset = 90)) # Offset by 90 days to March
```

[image]